# Scons and build from root and subdirs

Tags: build, scons

I'm trying out Scons and have a problem arranging it to my liking. I have two related projects, one with production code, other with tests for it arranged in following way:

- Root
- Root/Production
- Root/UnitTests

I would like to configure my build so that I can type:

1. scons - from Root to build both
2. scons from Production to build only production code
3. scons from UnitTests to build only unit tests

Now how would I go about it?
If I have SConstruct at root and SConscript in Production and UnitTests, I can only build from Root. But if I have SConscript at each level, with Root's one calling those in subdirs:

```
    # Just call Sconscripts for src and unitTests
    SConscript('production/SConstruct')
    SConscript('unitTests/SConstruct')
```

then while it does build as intended, it spits out of loads of warning about `Two different environments were specified for target (...)`. In this case indeed builds between Production and Tests are fairy similar, but once I get scons to work like I want it to, I would move to managing in a larger suite of projects which aren't necessarily related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a SConstruct in each directory, and also a SConscript in each directory. The SConstruct script would simply call the SConscripts, where all the logic would be. Something like this:

```
Root/SConstruct
Root/Production/SConstruct
Root/Production/SConscript
Root/UnitTests/SConstruct
Root/UnitTests/SConscript
```

The contents of each could be as follows:

**Root/SConstruct**

```
env = Environment()

# build stuff in this dir

# now call subdir SConscripts
SConscript('Root/Production/SConscript', exports='env')
SConscript('Root/UnitTests/SConscript',  exports='env')
```

**Root/Production/SConstruct**

```
env = Environment()

SConscript('SConscript', exports='env')
```

**Root/Production/SConscript**

```
# This SConscript will be called either from the Root/SConstruct
# or Root/Production/SConstruct

Import('env')

# Build stuff here
```

**Root/UnitTests/SConstruct**

```
env = Environment()

SConscript('SConscript', exports='env')
```

**Root/UnitTests/SConscript**

```
# This SConscript will be called either from the Root/SConstruct
# or Root/UnitTests/SConstruct

Import('env')

# Build stuff here
```

Notice that the SConscript scripts dont create an `Environment()`, but instead use the one passed in from either Root/SConstruct or the SConstruct in the same dir.

Also consider using the `variant_dir` parameter with the `SConscript()` function calls to place all the build output in a directory structure apart from the code directory structure. When doing so, also consider using the `duplicate=0` parameter with the `SConscript()` function call. The SConscript function is detailed [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html), [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c3186.html), and [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c3361.html).